# How to retrieve data from input without refresh, form, and submit button ? (Ajax, Jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How to get data from input without refresh, form, and submit button (jquery & ajax) like comment facebook ?

Get data when input on enter.

```
<body>
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="komentar" type="text">
<script>
$('#komentar').submit(function() {
console.log($('#komentar').val());
});
</body>
```

Comment: that is what ajax can do

Comment: example ? just get data,,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Comment: Search before write your question there are a lot of answers to your questions

Comment: the reason I am writing because I have not found the right answer.

how to input data without <form>, and submit button without refresh page ..?

if you can please write here

Answer (score 0):

Use keypress, if you want to get the data when user presses enter.

```
 <body>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="komentar" type="text">
    <script>
       $('#komentar').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
           console.log($('#komentar').val());
        }});
    </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: take the data when press enter in keyboard, not when typed or writing

Answer (score 0):

Submit will do the post back. So, we need to use `click()` instead of `submit` as below

```
`<script>
    $('#komentar').click(function(){
       console.log('');
    });
</script>`
```

Or use
    `<button>INSTEAD OF INPUT</button>`
if possible